# Blazor httpclient endpoint address configs

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm playing around with Blazor in .net core 3 preview 5.

My solution is quite simple, with one project for the web api and a second for the blazor client app.

The api is currently serving on localhost:5000 and the blazor app on localhost:5001, and I'm using httpclient to make http calls to the rest endpoint.

One thing in struggling with is understanding the best way to avoid baking in the api server URLs into the blazor app.

Is there am established pattern which will enable be to specify the base url by config or run time?

Edit to add info from comment:

Ultimately, I'd like to run it in a container in our test k8s cluster, that means the target url for the api would change to (say) api.test.companydns.com. the blazor app will end up running inside a container, so ideally I could pass in the api url as a parameter. I wasnt sure of the best way to do that as the blazor code ends up being executed on the client side

Comment: You want "The api is currently serving on localhost:5000" as fixed?

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to run it in a container in our test k8s cluster, that means the target url for the api would change to (say) api.test.companydns.com. the blazor app will end up running inside a container, so ideally I could pass in the api url as a parameter. I wasnt sure of the best way to do that as the blazor code ends up being executed on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Question:
      Is there am established pattern which will enable be to specify the **base url** by config or run time?

Answer: Yes, the base Uri of your Blazor client side is determined by the  `<base>` HTML element set in /wwwroot/index.html like so:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. I'm just writing up abit of a hack which I came up with. However, will this work if the blazor client app is served off test.blazorapp.com and the api is api.blazorapp.com? I read your resonse as prefxing the base path (blazorapp.com/blazor).

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of a hack which works for me (posted more to show I'm putting effort into solving the problem for myself!!):

I've added a config file to wwwroot\config\config.json which contains:

```
{
  "apiBaseUrl": "api.url.com"
}
```

Next, I've created an AppState.cs which used the HttpClient to download and store the base URL (Defaul DI instance of HttpClient has a BaseURL of the url serving the Blazor client app).

The AppState class is then made available using DI, so now all my Services can make calls to the new endpoint.

Lastly, I can use a build pipeline / CI / Docker volume / K8s config map to supply the relivent config.json depending on the hosting environment and without further changes to any Blazor app code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the problem you're facing as well as the solution you've come up with. I would recommend filing an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/asppnetcore repo regarding this gap, so the team behind Blazor (and I'm part of it) knows the specific use case and starts collecting more details about it.

Comment: How were you able to read file under wwwroot folder in a client side blazor app as there is no concept of IHostingEnvironment ??